# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBLazyVector"

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

While running command **"pod install"** it show me this:

`[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBLazyVector": In Podfile: FBLazyVector (from` ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector`)

Specs satisfying the `FBLazyVector (from` ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`

I'm trying to install pods in react native project but getting error and I want to resolve this error.